# VBA stop processing at first empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I have [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) that produces a flat text file of the selected column.

The issue is that the process takes a while because usually the column letter is clicked and the whole column is highlighted including all the unused cells.

How can i get the macro to stop processing when it finds the first empty row?

Here is my code.

```
Sub testlist()
Open "C:\Users\gaum\Desktop\Work\NCL\testlist.lst" For Output As #1
For NR = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
For NC = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
ExpData = Selection.Cells(NR, NC).Value
If IsNumeric(ExpData) Then ExpData = Val(ExpData)
If IsEmpty(Selection.Cells(NR, NC)) Then ExpData = ""
If NC <> NumCols Then
If Not ExpData = "FilePath" Then Print #1, ExpData
End If
Next NC
Next NR
Close #1
End Sub
```

Also am i able to get the macro to produce the output if i have multiple selections i.e ctrl and left click various cells, it currently only outputs the first highlight.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked 2 separate questions, I will address them both separately.

The easiest way to stop processing when you encounter a blank row is to add a check before your 2nd `For..Next` loop.  The issue is how to check.  The simplest way to check if an entire range is empty is to use the `CountA` worksheet function.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(NR & ":" & NR).EntireRow) = 0 Then Exit For
```

The above will basically use the worksheet function `CountA` and count the number of cells within the range that are not blank (using `CountA` is important here as the `Count` worksheet function will only count numeric cells and not non-numeric ones, whereas `CountA` will count anything except blanks.  The other advantage you get by using the `WorksheetFunction` object is you can adjust the `Range` object as you need if you only want to check a few columns and the not the entire row by just specifying the specific `Range` and not using `.EntireRow`.

---

The next question is how to deal with multiple selected ranges.  There is another member of the `Selection` class called [`Areas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197473.aspx), which should given you the functionality you need.  `Areas` is a collection that has the ranges for each individual selection range you make.

You can reference each selection range independently by using the 1-based index of the selection:

```
NumAreaRows = Selection.Areas(1).Rows.Count 'gets the number of rows in the first selected range
NumAreaCols = Selection.Areas(2).Columns.Count 'gets the number of columns in the second selected range
```

---

So you could put both all together into your solution:

```
Sub testlist()
    Open "C:\Users\gaum\Desktop\Work\NCL\testlist.lst" For Output As #1

    For NA = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
        For NR = 1 To Selection.Areas(NA).Rows.Count

            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(NR & ":" & NR).EntireRow) = 0 Then Exit For

            For NC = 1 To Selection.Areas(NA).Columns.Count
                ExpData = Selection.Areas(NA).Cells(NR, NC).Value
                If IsNumeric(ExpData) Then ExpData = Val(ExpData)
                If IsEmpty(Selection.Areas(NA).Cells(NR, NC)) Then ExpData = ""
                If NC <> NumCols Then
                    If Not ExpData = "FilePath" Then Print #1, ExpData
                End If
            Next NC
        Next NR
    Next NA
    Close #1
End Sub
```

The placement of the `CountA` function and the `Exit For` statement here allows you to loop through each selected range independently and it won't exit completely if you have a blank row in one of the ranges.

Comment: As I posted in my answer, range loops should be avoided as they are typically are very slow, and it was posted that *process takes a while*.  Also, for consistency, the `COUNTA` in the answere above should apply to the `Selection` - not the entire row

Comment: @brettdj I was working off of the OP's statement that `How can i get the macro to stop processing when it finds the first empty row?`  I agree that there are faster methods than `COUNTA` on the entire row but his, now deleted, comment (that was posted as an answer) suggested your answer wasn't quite want he wanted so I went with exactly as was described in his post.

Comment: My comment was more about that the Counta (a good test) should be applied to the intersect of the selection rather than the entire row. Yes, I did see that now deleted comment, I do test all my code pre posting so not sure why it failed for theOP :)

Answer (score 0):

Given this process takes a while, you would be better off going beyond stopping at a blank cell, and removing the inefficient range loop altogether. The code below

- Uses a variant array rather than range
- removes the redundant two-step `IF` test (if `ExpData` is numeric it cannot *also* be `"FilePath"`)

**code**

```
Sub testlist()
Dim X
Dim lngCnt As Long
X = Selection
If IsEmpty(X) Then Exit Sub
Open "C:\Users\gaum\Desktop\Work\NCL\testlist.lst" For Output As #1
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
If Len(X(lngCnt, 1)) = 0 Then Exit For
If IsNumeric(X(lngCnt, 1)) Then Print #1, Val(X(lngCnt, 1))
Next
Close #1
End Sub
```